# Navbar colour doesn't look right

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, navbar

I've set my navbar to white or atleast tried to. However, it hasn't come out looking very white it seems.

Here's the bit of code where I set it.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self addSidebarNavButton];

        // Set the navbar
        [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
        UILabel *nav_titlelbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationItem.titleView.frame.size.width,40)];
        nav_titlelbl.text=@"";
        nav_titlelbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        UIFont *lblfont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:20];
        [nav_titlelbl setFont:lblfont];
        self.navigationItem.titleView=nav_titlelbl;

        // Set the navbar colour
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor =
        [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0f green:255.0/255.0f blue:255.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Unfortunately I can't attach the navbar image here as I don't have the 10 reputation points needed. However if I could, you'd see that the navbar in question comes out looking light gray!

Comment: Have you tried `self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]` ?  If that doesn't work try setting `.translucent = NO`

Comment: Yes, you nailed it! This fixed it. self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Comment: Great, it was probably because the background was showing through.  I added the answer below so the question can be completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` you might be seeing the view background.